# Good practice for using "NOT IN" in a LINQ query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have converted the following SQL query to LINQ with the exception of the "NOT IN" subquery.

What would be the most effective way to implement this using LINQ? Should I use a join instead?

If anybody is able to provide an example or some guidance, I'd appreciate it.

New LINQ Query:

```
     return from objOpenCalls in db.OpenItemss
               from objTasks in db.Tasks
                .Where(t => (t.Task_ID == objOpenCalls.Parent_Task_ID))
                where ((objTasks.Item_ID > 0) && (objTasks.Type_ID > 0) && (objTasks.OwnerTypeItem_ID == user)  && (objOpenCalls.CallEnd < DateTime.Now))
                orderby objOpenCalls.CallStart descending
               select new CallMiniViewModel
               {
                   ID = objOpenCalls.ID,
                   CallStart = objOpenCalls.CallStart,
                   Name = objTasks.Task_Title
               };
```

Old SQL Query:

```
SELECT  TOP (100) ta.ID, t.Task_Title, ta.CallStart
FROM         OpenItems AS ta INNER JOIN
                      Tasks AS t ON ta.Parent_Task_ID = t.Task_ID
WHERE   
(t.Item_ID > 0) AND (t.[Type_ID] > 0) AND (ta.CallStart > DATEADD(m, -6, GETDATE())) 
AND (ta.ID NOT IN (SELECT     CallId FROM CallFeedback)) AND (t.OwnerTypeItem_ID = @Username)     AND (ta.CallEnd < GETDATE())
ORDER BY ta.CallStart DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing the not in. Below is just a quick sample put in LinqPad as a test.

```
class MyClass {
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

void Main()
{
    int[] myItems = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    IEnumerable<MyClass> classes = new []{ 
        new MyClass { Id = 3 },
        new MyClass { Id = 6 },
        new MyClass { Id = 8 }
    };

    var results = from cl in classes
                    where !myItems.Contains( cl.Id ) 
                    select cl;                                  

    foreach(var result in results) {
        Console.WriteLine( "Class {0}", result.Id);
    }

    var results2 = from cl in classes
                    where ( 
                        from i in myItems
                        where i == cl.Id
                        select i ).Count( ) == 0 
                    select cl;

    foreach(var result in results2) {
        Console.WriteLine( "Class {0}", result.Id);
    }               

}
```

I normally play with code first in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) as it helps me understand any problems, and it will (if you're working with SQL) then show you what SQL the query will generate and you can fine tune a little.  Sometimes it takes a little time to get your stuff able to be run in there, but it's worth it with the more complex queries.